# How to make FullCalendar grid (vertical & horizontal line) thickness change?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am a beginner of fullCalendar user.
How to make FullCalendar grid thickness 3 more px ? default grid is too thin.

[image: FullCalendar Grid]

Comment: Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a good question.

Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should be able to use CSS.  But be warned if you mess too much with the layout of the grid you can find that events do not show in the right place, as they are overlaid on top of the grid using positioning, rather than contained within it. I would question whether increasing the thickness of the grid lines is really that important.

Comment: Thank ADyson reply. when view that calendar on small size screen on mobile. I could see date only. If grid could change slight thickness, it make a big difference.